# R ifelse statement with nested conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

```
x=data.frame("l"=c('a','b','d','a','c','c','d'),
             "t"=c(1:7))
x$l1 = ifelse(x$l=="a",1,
              ifelse(x$l=="b",2,
                     ifelse(x$l=="c",3,
                            ifelse(x$l=="d" ,4,
                                   ifelse(x$l=="d" & x$t==7,5,NA)))))
```

As you can see on the final statement, if `l == "d" & t == 7` then l1 should equals to 5 but it gets set equals to 4.

Answer (score 3):

`ifelse` execution stops wherever it first hits `TRUE`.

Simply reordering your conditions -

```
x$l1 = ifelse(x$l=="a",1,
              ifelse(x$l=="b",2,
                     ifelse(x$l=="c",3,
                            ifelse(x$l=="d" & x$t==7,5,
                                   ifelse(x$l=="d" ,4,NA)))))
x
  l t l1
1 a 1  1
2 b 2  2
3 d 3  4
4 a 4  1
5 c 5  3
6 c 6  3
7 d 7  5
```

Also consider using `case_when()` from `dplyr` package; it would be much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

It is better not to use any nested `ifelse` or `case_when`.  This can be done much easily and efficiently with a key/value dataset merge

```
keydat <- data.frame(l = letters[1:4],l1 = 1:4)
left_join(x, keydat) %>%
     mutate(l1 = replace(l1, l== 'd' & t == 7, 5))
#  l t l1
#1 a 1  1
#2 b 2  2
#3 d 3  4
#4 a 4  1
#5 c 5  3
#6 c 6  3
#7 d 7  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Shree's answer, here it comes the `tidyverse` version:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

x <- data.frame("l"=c('a','b','d','a','c','c','d'),
             "t"=c(1:7))


x %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(l1 = case_when(
    l == "a" ~ 1,
    l == "b" ~ 2,
    l == "c" ~ 3,
    l == "d" & t == 7 ~ 5,
    l == "d" ~ 4
  ))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   l         t    l1
#>   <fct> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     1
#> 2 b         2     2
#> 3 d         3     4
#> 4 a         4     1
#> 5 c         5     3
#> 6 c         6     3
#> 7 d         7     5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>